Engine leaks (Datsun Go 1.2 2015
My car recently heating up the water and I realized the fan is not running. I was told to replace the thermostat for the fan to run again, already at the time it was heating up and loosing water. I first changed the Top gasket because I was told its also causing the problem. After changing the top Gasket the engine seemed fine until recently again its doing the same thing loosing water.
I haven't replaced the Thermostat because of availability, so the mechanic said we must unplug the switch until I replace the thermostat. The car is loosing water again indicating heating up the water. I'm not sure what to do...
Does this mean I need engine overhaul?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
